# Vulkan VK_EXT_multi_draw per draw Push Constant

Tags: vulkan

Is it possible to provide Push Constants for each draw in `vkCmdDrawMultiEXT`. I'm currently using Push Constants to push the Model matrix to VS and would like to do so aswell with multi Draw.
However I couldn't find any Information regarding this in the Extension Specs. The idea would be to push N matrices and then call DrawMulti for N objects

```
vkCmdPushConstants(modelMatrix1);
vkCmdPushConstants(modelMatrix2);
vkCmdPushConstants(modelMatrix3);
vkCmdPushConstants(modelMatrix4);
vkCmdDrawMultiEXT(drawCount = 4);`
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is just a CPU-buffer-based version (and a limited one at that) of the standard function `vkCmdDrawIndirect`. The difference is that the standard function takes the draw call data from GPU-accessible memory, while the extension takes it from CPU-allocated memory. But the overall functionality is the same.

That means it doesn't affect the nature of push constants and the like. Push constants remain a small block of easily changeable `uniform` storage that cannot change within a draw call. Even if that draw call has multiple draw calls within it.

The general way to do what you're asking for is to use `gl_DrawIndex` in the vertex shader to fetch the per-model data from some SSBO or the like. `gl_DrawIndex` will be the same for all vertices generated from the same draw call, but will change between draw calls.